# Extracting array inside an object coming from API call

Tags: angular, rxjs

My api call returns data the following way:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "descp": "item 1",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "descp": "item 2",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "descp": "item 3",
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to get the array of items from this using rxjs but have not been able to so far. I keep running into
`core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected.`

```
  getItems() {
    const iAmStuck$ = this.service.getAllItems();
    iAmStuck$
      .pipe(mergeMap((insideArray) => insideArray))
      .subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
  }
```

service call

```
  getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    const url = `${environment.url}/allItems`;
    return this.http.get<Item[]>(url);
  }
```

I created the following interfaces

```
export interface IInsideItems{
  id: number;
  descp: string;
}

export interface Item{
  items: IInsideItems[];
}
```

In the end of all this, I want to put `id` and `descp` into a new array of `IDropdown`

```
IDropdown{
 id: string;
 descp: string;
}
```

Comment: Please include the code for `getAllItems` function. Also, what is your desired outcome? Your comment in the code: `<-- how to return a stream` can be answered just by saying "Use `return`", but I guess that's not exactly what you're wondering. Be specific.

Comment: @DanielB, added more information. Thanks.

Comment: Is your content type defined?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `mergeMap`? That's whats causing you problems.

Comment: @DanielB,  I was trying to use `mergeMap` and then `map` to get the data out but I guess that is not the right way

Comment: @ViníciusMussato, it wont make a difference if I have types defined or not. The object coming from api call with still be the same and I need to extract the array inside the object.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct service? You call `const iAmStuck$ = this.service.getAllItems();` but your service is called `getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {`. Maybe there is another service `getAllItems` in parallel, which doesn't return an observable?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm, I realized that I was doing 2 things wrong. My interface of `Item` should not be an array in the api call. Once I fixed that, I was able to get my item to work. I want to delete this question but it wont let me since my problem was not what I mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `mergeMap`, you only need `map`. You don't even need to `subscribe` anywhere. The error you get is from using `mergeMap`, since it expects a stream as argument, not an actual object. Your code could work with `mergeMap` if you would wrap `insideArray.items` in the `of` operator.

I assume you have a template in which you want to populate your dropdown with your values. The best way to get the values from your observable is to simply return the observable itself, and let Angulars `async` pipe handle the subscribe/unsubscribe for you.

Your `getItems()` would become

```
getItems() {
   return this.service.getAllItems(
        map(response => response.items) // We use map to return the items of the response
   );
}
```

and you could then use that in a template

```
<select name="" id="">
  <option *ngFor="let item of getAllItems() | async" [value]="item.id">{{item.descp}}</option>
</select>
```

I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zujyfd?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) example for you to look at that demonstrates this with a mocked response. The example isn't with types, but I don't see why that wouldn't work.

As a rule of thumb, try to minimize your manual subscriptions as much as possible, and instead work with the observables. Mixing reactive and imperative programming, such as subscribing and then assigning the unwrapped observable value to a variable is bad practice. You should instead (as I suggested above) return or use the observable itself.